# So far, no updates for natty in repos?

Tags: 11.04, updates

Okay, i'm just a bit nervous. since i updated from maverick to natty, i didn't download any updates. yes, now the third day goes after stable release and so far update-manager hasn't found or downloaded any updates. is that for real?
i'm wondering because even for 10.10 STILL some updates are coming on a daily basis. And for fresh and not-enough-stable release there are no updates for almost three days?

Tell me that there's nothing wrong with my update-manager and there hasn't been any updates indeed.

Answer (score 2):

There are now updates for packages such as firefox.  It may be that you don't have any packages installed that need updates, or perhaps the updates have not propagated to your mirror yet.

You can see this by running for instance

```
% rmadison firefox

....
firefox | 4.0+nobinonly-0ubuntu3 |         natty | source, amd64, i386
firefox | 4.0+nobinonly-0ubuntu3 |       oneiric | source, amd64, i386
firefox | 4.0.1+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 | natty-security | source, amd64, i386
firefox | 4.0.1+build1+nobinonly-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 | natty-updates | source, amd64, i386
```

However, these actually came out even before the final release of Natty, so you probably already have them.

If you want to check if your machine is updating ok, what I would do is run `sudo apt-get update` from a terminal and make sure that it's really reloading its indexes from the right server.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your Update Manager - there simply haven't been any updates yet. There will be in time, no need to worry.